# How can i set master/detail view side by side in portrait mode using uisplitviewcontroller

Tags: swift, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using the new UISplitViewController, coming with iOS 14 as follows:

```swift
let splitViewController = UISplitViewController(style: .doubleColumn)
splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .oneBesideSecondary

let primaryVC = PrimaryViewController()
splitViewController.setViewController(primaryVC, for: .primary)

let secondaryVC = SecondaryViewController()
splitViewController.setViewController(secondaryVC, for: .secondary)
```

It works as expected, but i wanted to get a similiar result like this:

[image]

**Landscape**
i want to only have a expand icon in the secondaryViewController to hide or show the sidebar as you maybe also know from the Apple Notes App for iPad. I want to hide/remove default Sidebar Icon.

**Portrait**
i want the primary and secondary view side-by-side. With the new UISplitViewController, the primary view always collapsed and you get a "Back" Button in the NavigationBar.

So is there a way to manipulate or customize the new UISplitViewController to get the result, as i described above?

**What i tried**
switch to the "classic" UISplitViewController like this:

```swift
let splitViewController = UISplitViewController(style: .unspecified)
```

but with the style `unspecified` i get the following runtime error:

```
API misuse. -initWithStyle: may not be used with UISplitViewControllerStyleUnspecified
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case the style should be `doubleColumn`, as it's what you want to achieve in both portrait and landscape mode.

Try to implement this method in the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`:

```
optional func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, 
              collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, 
                             onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
```

And if not already set, set your `UISplitViewController's` delegate. Return false if you don't want to collapse the split view controller (which means that if not collapsed, it will display two columns; Which is your case).